# Prove that $G=\{g^{-1}f(g):g\in G\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Assume that $G$ is a finite group, $f:G \to G$ is an isomorphism, and $f\circ f={id}_G$.
For each $g \in G-\{e_g\}$, We have $f(g) \neq g$, Prove that $G$ is an abelian group.

The question also provides a hint :

First, Prove that $G=\{g^{-1}f(g):g\in G\}$.

My problem solving the question:

I don't know how to prove the thing that the hint wants! Otherwise i'm done. I know how to show that $G$ is abelian if $G=\{g^{-1}f(g):g\in G\}$ is proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove that $\phi: g \mapsto g^{-1}f(g)$ is injective.
Since $G$ is finite, $\phi$ is surjective.

Note that $\phi$ is not necessarily a homomorphism, but that is not needed.

Comment: How do we see that $\phi$ is injective?  I don't see anything obvious here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Then you forgot to use the assumption that $f$ has no no non-trivial fixed points.

Comment: @MooS Ah! That will do it.  Need to read more closely next time